# In this Stirling Engine process, how do we know that the fluid is heating up?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

[image]

Since the volume of fluid in contact with the cold source and hot source is the same, how do we know the fluid is heating up instead of cooling down?

Comment: See https://www.stirlingengine.com/diagram/

Comment: The displacer (yellow, in your diagram) separates the working fluid into two parts; the cold side (blue) and the hot side (pink). As the displacer moves up and down, fluid flows around the edge of it from one side to the other. When the displacer moves up, cold fluid moves toward the hot side, where it is heated up by the flames. When the displacer moves down, hot fluid moves to the cold side, where it is cooled down by the running water.

Comment: P.S., The diagram does a poor job of showing that the displacer is connected to a crank, just like the crank to which the green piston is connected, but the two cranks are offset by 90 degrees.

Comment: I understand that the position of piston is fixed at the bottom dead centre during the isochoric heating process (and because they're connected, the displacer doesn't move too), and the diagram seems to show that the displacer will be in the middle of the fluid, causing the volume of the fluid in contact with the cold and hot source to be the same - so I'm still quite confused whether the fluid is heating up or cooling down?

Answer (score 0):

> ...the diagram seems to show that the displacer...in the middle of the fluid, causing the volume of the fluid in contact with the cold and hot source to be the same - so I'm still quite confused whether the fluid is heating up or cooling down?

OK, I get it now. I think the machine is not self-starting. If you grab hold of the flywheel and stop it for long enough in any position, then the pressure of the working fluid will stop changing. If the pressure at that moment happens to be close to ambient (which it soon will be if the piston and cylinder are at all leaky) then when you let go, there will be no force to start it turning again.

In normal operation, the piston alternately pushes on and pulls on its crank, but there must be a position in-between when it is doing neither. Normally, the inertia of the flywheel is what keeps the machine in motion through those positions.